# VBA - Get String Associated with Max Value in Range

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am in the process of writing a macro in excel and need to get the string or text associated with the max value in a range.

My range looks something like this:

A | B 
CR1 | 2.33 
CR2 | 5.1 
CR3 | 10.0 
CR4 | 3.8

I was able to find the MAX value in column B, but now I need the associated string in column A.  So in this case, given B3 (10.0) is the max value, I want to pull out 'CR3'.

So my code for pulling the max value is:

```
 Set myRange = Application.InputBox( _
 prompt:="Please select the Range.", Title:="Graph Range", Type:=8)
 highestNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)
```

What can I do to get the associated string in column A?
I've tried using .Address, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

!!!!!!! Edit/Update - Solved: !!!!!!!

As another contributer suggested, I needed to use inded + Match.  See below for Solution.

```
Set myRange = Application.InputBox( _
prompt:="Please select the Primary KPI 'Lift' Data to Graph.", Title:="Graph Range", Type:=8)

Set rngColumn2 = myRange.Areas(2)

highestNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)

test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(myRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(highestNum, rngColumn2, 1), 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an [index(Match,Match)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=index%20match%20excel) function.
It would take a look at the highest number in B and return the A.

Comment: this lead my down the right path.  See my edited post for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the recognition :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Range.Find() to return the cell in which the max value is found.

Then use offset to return the value from the cell directly to the left:

```
 Dim mtch As Range
 Set myrange = Application.InputBox( _
 prompt:="Please select the Range.", Title:="Graph Range", Type:=8)
 highestNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myrange)
 Set mtch = myrange.Find(highestNum)
 Debug.Print mtch.Offset(, -1).Value
```

---

Edit

It seems you are experiencing a rounding/floating decimal problem.  To help deal with that we need to change to a For Each loop and load each value into another double so the rounding is the same:

```
Dim mtch As Range
Dim highestNum As Double
Dim t As Double
Dim myrange As Range
 Set myrange = Application.InputBox( _
 prompt:="Please select the Range.", Title:="Graph Range", Type:=8)
 highestNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myrange)
 t = Range("B3").Value
 r = t = highestNum
 For Each mtch In myrange
    t = mtch.Value
    If t = highestNum Then
        Debug.Print mtch.Offset(, -1).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next mtch
```

Comment: I am getting a "Object Variable or with block variable not set"  Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: On which line?  What are the value of highestNum at the time of the error?

Comment: the debug.Print Line.  The value of highestNum is 0.0611...which happens to be the highest value in my actual data set.  highestNum is set to double if that helps.

Comment: It is not finding a match for some reason. Try @user3598756 code.  It might be a rounding/floating decimal issue.

Comment: @user2828701 see edit for a work around on the floating decimal.

Comment: @ Scott Craner - Thanks for helping me out.  Your latest edit did not help either, I continued to have issues.  I am editing my post above with the answer I ended up with.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just to play a little bit with Scott's solution:

```
With Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the Range.", Title:="Graph Range", Type:=8)
    Debug.Print Cells.Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells)).Offset(, -1).Value
End With
```